# Form #redirect not working?

Tags: 6, forms, users

I'm trying to make the user creation form redirect back to the home page when you submit it. I'm using Content Profiles so it is two forms sharing a submit button. Even if I set #redirect = '/' on both forms the form always redirects back to itself. It works and everything, but won't redirect how I want.

Any ideas?

Code:

```
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
      switch ($form_id) {
        case 'user_register':
        $form['#redirect'] = '/';
        break;
        case 'coordinator_node_form':
        $form['#redirect'] = '/';           
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see the code you're using?

Comment: There ya go. Hopefully you spot something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are two facts to keep in consideration about `$form['#redirect']`:

- `$form_state['#redirect']`, set in a form submission handler, takes the precedence over `$form['#redirect']`.
- `$form['#redirect']` and `$form_state['#redirect']` are ignored for forms where "#action" has been set by a module. That is what happen with the user login form.
- `$form['#redirect']` and `$form_state['#redirect']` are ignored when `$_REQUEST['destination']` is set; its value is instead used.

If you want to redirect a form, and be sure it gets redirected to the path you set, you should implement `hook_form_alter()` to add a form submission handler that alters `$form_state['#redirect']`. The module implementing that hook should be executed after other modules that alter `$form_state['#redirect']` for that module.
This doesn't have any effect, though, in the last two cases I listed before.

Comment: So is there any downside to my solution? Unsetting destination in hook_form_alter seems to work, but are there situations in which it won't work?

Comment: The "downside" is that you cannot be sure the user is effectively redirected to the page you want; it's enough another module adds a submission handler, and it sets `$form_state['#redirect']`.

Comment: So how do I redirect a form that has the action set?

Comment: You unset `$form['#action']`.

Comment: @kiamlaluno, thanks for the insight but where is all this information present in the FAPI documentation at Drupal site?

Comment: Part of what I wrote is understandable from the code of [drupal_redirect_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/drupal_redirect_form/6). I don't remember in which function is evident the Drupal's behavior for forms setting `$form['#action']`, but I remember that is the Drupal's behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Ok after much digging I found the answer here: http://drupal.org/node/934664

Apparently destination overwrites #redirect so I just unset destination and it works.