# Redirect node form in D7

Tags: redirection, forms

It looks like silly question but I'm really confused about redirection after node save and update.

I tried to set `$form['#redirect']` - without any success.
I tried to set some other vars for instance: `$_REQUEST['destination']` or in `$form['buttons']['submit']['#submit']` setting function name to call that sets `$form_state['#redirect']` but none of this solution works.

Can you give me some source that explains node forms redirecting in D7?

Comment: I've just seen http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/11306/7184 - it seems some other module destroys my rediretcs.

Comment: This does my head in fairly often too; I usually just go 'old-school' and redirect the page manually: `header('Location: /new-page'); drupal_exit();`. It's not the best but it does get the job done

Comment: I see your point but I'm not convinced in 'old-school' solutions. They break rules of good development. But saying it in Drupal world... sic! Thanks for advice I'll search for a time for prettier solution a I'm hope I won't should go back to this. :)

Comment: Using PHP functions in Drupal is certainly not breaking any rules of development. If you look at the `drupal_goto()` function, all it does is internally set headers. If anything you're optimising your code by removing an extra function call overhead :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Use hook_node_create and hook_node_update, judge your node type to drup_goto, like:

```
function hook_node_create ($node) {
  if ($node->type == 'YOUR_NODE_TYPE') {
     drupal_goto('YOUR_DESTINATION');
  }
}
```

2.Use hook_form_alter change your node form, like:

```
function hook_form_alter (&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'YOUR_NODE_FORM_ID') {
    $form['actions']['submit']['#submit'][] = 'YOUR_NODE_FORM_ID_ls_submit';
  } 
}

function YOUR_NODE_FORM_ID_ls_submit ($form, &$form_state) {
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'YOUR_DESTINATION'; // Not $form_state['#redirect']
}
```

Comment: Problem is neither of these methods will work if the `destination` parameter is set in the URL. That trumps everything and you have to reset the static cache if you want to override it

Comment: The second way is working! Thanks a lot! `destination` parameter isn't my concern.

Comment: So, according to first method, I used it with `hook_node_delete` and noticed that redirection works but node isn't deleting anymore. Do you have any solution regarding deletion?

Comment: @kobylecki You should not use `drupal_goto()` on any node hook, or you are interrupting the action being done.

Comment: In hook_node_create and hook_node_update, shhould be node has been created and updated.

Comment: @kiamlaluno and Rylyn: OK, I get it. (I'm not sure if you understand me) Here is my question: how to redirect after node delete?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add a new submit callback to your validate button with a hook_form_alter and add a $form_state['redirect'] :

```
mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id){
$form['actions']['submit']['#submit][] = 'mymodule_redirect_callback';
}

mymodule_redirect_callback($form, &$form_state){
$form_state['redirect'] = array('___your__phath____');
}
```

Don't forget to pass the $form_state variable in your callback BY REFERENCE ( '&$form_state' and not juste '$form_state').

I used this method hundreds of times.

Finally, don't forget that a 'destination' parameter in the URL will always override any redirect set in $form_state['redirect'].
See [drupal_redirect_form](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/drupal_redirect_form/7) for more information

Answer (score 0):

There is the [Node Save Redirect](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_save_redirect) module for this purpose. Check it out! Here is a quote about it (from the module's project page):

> ... provides a method of specifying a location to take the user after saving a piece of content.
>
> A set of radios buttons are added to the submission vertical tab on the content type edit form.
>
> The available options are:
>
> - Default - Default behaviour
> - Return to Edit page after saving
> - Return to content overview page (assuming the user has access permissions
> - Re-redirect to another location. (any valid drupal path)