# Redirect on node form submit with custom module - hook_form_alter

Tags: redirection, forms

I have Druapl 6 with orgranic groups installed. I need a thing - when a group user creates "group" content after node form submission he must be redirected back on group homepage instead of node view page.

```
function heihachi_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  switch($form_id) {
        case 'group_wall_node_form':
        unset($form['buttons']['preview']);

        $redirect = 'node/' . $form['og_initial_groups']['#value'][0];
        $form_state['redirect'][0] = $redirect;
        //dpm($form);
        break;
  }
}
```

but that code doesn't redirect at all. Using simple $form['#redirect'] works, but it affects Node delete button aswell, so i can't delete my node because it redirects on a custom path. Thanks for all advices in advance.

**My new code (not working also):**

```
function heihachi_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  switch($form_id) {
        case 'group_wall_node_form':
        unset($form['buttons']['preview']);
        $form['#submit'][] = 'custom_redirect';
        //dpm($form);
        break;
  }
}

function custom_redirect($form, &$form_state) {

  //unset($_REQUEST['destination']);
  //unset($form['#redirect']);

  $form_state['rebuild'] = TRUE;

  $redirect = 'node/' . $form['og_initial_groups']['#value'][0];
  $form_state['redirect'] = $redirect;
}
```

**This is what i see in $form variable:**

0 (String, 21 characters ) menu_node_form_submit | (Callback) menu_node_form_submit();

1 (String, 31 characters ) auto_nodetitle_node_form_submit | (Callback) auto_nodetitle_node_form_submit();

2 (String, 15 characters ) custom_redirect | (Callback) custom_redirect();

I guess something wrong is there?

**SOLVED!**

used hook_nodeapi as one guy told me below:

```
function heihachi_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $teaser = NULL, $page = NULL) {
  if ($node->type == 'group_wall') {
    if ($op == 'insert') {
      $_REQUEST['destination'] = 'xxx';
    }
  }
```

Comment: This post might help: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34548/redirect-node-form-in-d7

Comment: Instead of `$form_state['redirect'] = $redirect;` try `drupal_goto` in `custom_redirect` function.

Comment: with drupal_goto() my cck fields won't save!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `hook_nodeapi` with op `insert` or add another submit function in `hook_form_alter`.

Comment: Adding a new submission function, IMO, is the best way. nodeapi hooks are somewhat expensive (you alter the form anyway so why hook again ?). Do NOT use drupal_got() in forms! Use $form_state['redirect'] instead. Also, it's better $form['buttons']['preview']['#access'] = FALSE; than unsetting it.

Comment: Thanks, $form_state['redirect'] is not working for me somehow...

Comment: @Heihachi I think you should write `$form_state['redirect']` in submit function.

Comment: Check my updated post please