# How to redirect search result page in drupal

Tags: theming, search, 7, views

Here, I am working in drupal Commons plugin. I already customized search form in that drupal header.Here i include modify search form in custom theme:

```
function mytheme_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'search_block_form') {
    $form['search_block_form']['#title'] = t('Search'); // Change the text on the label element
    $form['search_block_form']['#title_display'] = 'invisible'; // Toggle label visibilty
    $form['search_block_form']['#default_value'] = t('Search'); // Set a default value for the textfield
    $form['custom_search_types']['#attributes'] = array('style' => 'display:none'); // Set a default value for the textfield
    $form['search_block_form']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'form-control'; // Set a default value for the textfield
    $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = 'OK!'; // Change the text on the submit button

    $form['actions']['submit'] = array('#type' => 'button','#value' => 'OK!');

    // Add extra attributes to the text box
    $form['search_block_form']['#attributes']['onblur'] = "if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search';}";
    $form['search_block_form']['#attributes']['onfocus'] = "if (this.value == 'Search') {this.value = '';}";
    // Prevent user from searching the default text
    $form['#attributes']['onsubmit'] = "if(this.search_block_form.value=='Search'){ alert('Please enter a search'); return false; }";
    $form['actions']['submit']['#attributes']['class'][] = 'input-group-addon';

    // Alternative (HTML5) placeholder attribute instead of using the javascript
    $form['search_block_form']['#attributes']['placeholder'] = t('Search');
  }
}
```

And i need to redirect search result page using that above search form.But I type content and hit enter it remain same page.How to redirect into search result page with custom form values.I just customized form submit in custom theme

```
function mytheme_search_box_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
print_r($form);//No results 
}
```

How to achieve it. kindly guide me..

Comment: Maybe this thread will help you:
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/34548/redirect-node-form-in-d7

:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **redirect** attribute in form_state as follows,

```
function mytheme_search_box_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
   $form_state['#redirect'] = 'Your path to redirect';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complete example. First you add a custom form handler:

```
function yourmodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {

  switch ($form_id)  {

  case 'search_form':
    $form['#submit'][] = 'yourmodule_search_box_form_submit';
  break;

  }
}
```

Then you redirect. Here's an example adding the search terms to the URL:

```
function yourmodule_search_box_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {

   $search_terms = $form_state['input']['keys'];

   $form_state['redirect'] = 'some/path/'.check_url( $search_terms );

}
```

If it doesn't work, try adding `$form_state['rebuild'] = FALSE;` to the second function, and try toggling between `$form_state['redirect']` and `$form_state['#redirect']`