# sending parameters to external url and redirect to that url simultanously

Tags: redirection, forms

I saw this link:[Webform - Submit values from Drupal 7 from to external url](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/94884/webform-submit-values-from-drupal-7-from-to-external-url/130263#130263)

I have this problem too (sending parameters to external url and redirect to that url simultaneously)!

But I also want to redirect user, who submit the parameters to url, redirect to that url simultaneously!

my Code is:

```
function Chargingform_nameform() {
    $xml = 'PHP Handbook30000130000This is good book.MySQL Handbook25000250000This is a good book too.';
    // Get sing
    $sign ='ewtnXYRWPSalHhna9hgO+Kc0W9Z8JBUeG1FkcKPvZL5w2s588c0/B9rTki/Ry4vHuNG7uuPcttTAz/3j4e/5GcZ4L40jNyzK7dkQyEalRVOZNe9gdnSXMH7h8Q6OY5vwLENn7S4MGTMZCABRrmj1W9vviykftP4tv0EDtNkUgjU';   
    $form['xml'] = array(
        '#title' => t('xml'),
        '#type' =>'hidden',
        '#value'=>$xml,     
    );
    $form['sign'] = array(
        '#title' => t('sign'),
        '#type' =>'hidden',
        '#value'=>$sign,
    );   
     variable_set('xml_hidden', $xml);
     variable_set('sign_hidden', $sign);    
 $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('submit'),
    );
    return $form;
}


function Chargingform_nameform_submit($form, &$form_state) {  
$options = array();   
     $options = array(
        'method' => 'POST',       
        'xml' => $form_state['values']['xml'],
        'sign' => $form_state['values']['sign'],            
    );    
    $url = 'https//:url';    
    $response = drupal_http_request($url, $options);     
}
```

How should I solve this issue?

Comment: The code in the answer you linked to explains it, it should also direct the user to the external page. Please explain your problem a little better.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Form #redirect not working?](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/11268/form-redirect-not-working)